# how does mysql user defined function know a selected row was found?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

a MYSQL user defined function selects a row from a table.  How does the UDF code determine if the selected row was found in the table?

```
CREATE FUNCTION snippetFolder_folderPath(folder_id int)
  RETURNS varchar(512)
  BEGIN

  declare    vFolder_id int;
  declare    vParent_id int;
  declare    vPath varchar(512) default '';
  declare    vFolderName varchar(256) default '';

  set        vFolder_id = folder_id;
  build_path:
  while (vFolder_id > 0) do


/* -------- how to know this select statement returns a row??  ---------- */
  select     a.parent_id, a.folderName
  into       vParent_id, vFolderName
  from       SnippetFolder a
  where      a.folder_id = vFolder_id;

  if         vPath = ' ' then
  set        vPath = vFolderName;
else
  set        vPath = concat_ws( '/', vFolderName, vPath );
  end if ;

  set        vFolder_id = vParent_id;
  end while ;

  return vPath;

  END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html says:

> If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code 1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged.

So you could [declare a continue handler on warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html), something like the example from the documentation:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 3;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  retry:
    REPEAT
      BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
          BEGIN
            SET done = TRUE;
          END;
        IF done OR i < 0 THEN
          LEAVE retry;
        END IF;
        SET i = i - 1;
      END;
    UNTIL FALSE END REPEAT;
END
```

I'll leave it to you to read the documentation and adapt that example to your table and your loop.

Alternatively, if you're using MySQL 8.0 you can use recursive common table expression:

```
CREATE FUNCTION snippetFolder_folderPath(vFolder_id int)
  RETURNS varchar(512)
BEGIN

  DECLARE    vPath varchar(512) DEFAULT '';

  WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT folderName, parent_id, 0 AS height 
    FROM SnippetFolder WHERE folder_id = vFolder_id
    UNION
    SELECT f.folderName, f.parent_id, cte.height+1
    FROM SnippetFolder AS f JOIN cte ON cte.parent_id = f.folder_id 
  )
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(folderName ORDER BY height DESC SEPARATOR '/')
  INTO vPath
  FROM cte;

  RETURN vPath;
END
```

The recursive CTE result is all the ancestors of the row matching `vFolder_id`, and then one can use GROUP_CONCAT() to concatenate them together as one string.

Comment: can I load the error code into a variable?
in DB2 you declare a variable named SQLCODE.  Then, SQLCODE is set to 100 when no rows are returned.